# Can I generate Postfix Notation without using Double Linked List and Stack data structure

Tags: java, stack, queue, abstract-data-type, postfix-notation

my question is about "**postfix**" notation. In my project instructor has wanted from me to calculate postfix notations. Programming style is free but programming language is Java. I will write codes in Java but i don't good about abstract data types such as stack, queue. Is there a way to calculate postfix notations without stack, double linked list and queue?

Comment: Hi, hakiko. StackOverflow is a site where people come with specific question about the code they are writing. You are asking a completely general question with no code. So I'd say this is off-topic here.

Comment: I think question is simple and basic, is there a way or not. I will research after yours answer :)

Comment: As it stands, your question is ill-defined. What does it mean to "calculate postfix notation"?

Comment: I apologize for my English firstly. I have this "postfix notation" expression " 5 9 + 2 * 6 5 * + " So , and i must solve it.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Any code at all? Such a postfix expression is definitely most easily handled by a stack-oriented routine.

Comment: 'Generate postfix notation'? 'Evaluate postfix notation'? Which is it? What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would work WITH a stack:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String in = "5 9 + 2 * 6 5 * +";
  final Deque<Object> s = new LinkedList();
  for (String t : in.split(" ")) {
    if (t.equals("+")) s.push((Integer)s.pop() + (Integer)s.pop());
    else if (t.equals("*")) s.push((Integer)s.pop() * (Integer)s.pop());
    else s.push(Integer.parseInt(t));
  }
  System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```